# Installation of CRF++: the command. / configure does not work

Tags: windows, crf++

I want to install ***CRF++ toolkit on windows***. But, I have a problem with the command **./configure**. It doesn't work.
Is there anyone who could help me. Thanks

Comment: can you please post your error here??

Comment: If you want to Install and use CRF++ on Windows : https://youtu.be/pAplsqK1bAk

Answer (score 4):

You can't use `./configure` on windows, becouse this is a Linux command. For windows, you need to download the right version(of course, win [cfrpp](http://code.google.com/p/crfpp/downloads/list)) of CRF++. You can see 3 main files :`crf_learn.exe`, `crf_test.exe` and `libcrfpp.dll`. Please find [cfrpp usage](http://crfpp.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/index.html#usage) For futher infomation.